# Error 500 al cargar un archivo PDF con ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, post

Estoy intentando guardar un archivo PDF en base64 en una base de datos. Y todo funciona perfectamente. Sin embargo, si intento guardar un archivo PDF que pese más de 2MB me sale el siguiente error:

> *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)*

La petición POST del ajax ni siquiera llega al Controller. Pero si es un archivo menor a 2MB sí llega al Controller y lo guarda correctamente.
¿Hay alguna limitante en ajax para realizar una petición POST? ¿O saben cómo podría definir el peso máximo aceptado de un archivo?

Aquí dejo las funciones js.
La variable **archivoev** es la que me almacena el string en base64 que envío al Controller.

```
$(document).on('click', '#BtnGuardarDocumento', function (e) {
var Mensaje = ValidaCamposRequeridos(".CampoReq");
if (Mensaje.length == 0) {
    if (archivoev != "") {
        var datosDocumento = {
            IdDocumento: $('#IdDocumento').val(),
            Encabezado: $("#TxtEncabezado").val(),
            Cuerpo: $("#TxtCuerpo").val(),
            Archivo: archivoev,
            Activo: $("#ChckActivo").prop("checked")
        }
        LlamadaGuardarDocumento(datosDocumento);
    }
    else
        MensajeAdvertencia("El archivo es requerido.");
}
else
    MensajeAdvertencia(Mensaje);
})

function LlamadaGuardarDocumento(datosDocumento) {
    var url = $("#urlGuardarDocumento").val();
$.ajax({

    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ datosDocumento: datosDocumento }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: successLlamadaGuardarDocumento,
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        MensajeError(errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

Este es el Controller que recibe los parámetros

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GuardarDocumento(DocumentacionModel datosDocumento)
    {
        var resultado = new JObject();
        if (!FuncionesGenerales.SesionActiva())
        {
            resultado["Exito"] = false;
            resultado["Advertencia"] = false;
            resultado["SesionDesactiva"] = true;
            resultado["UrlLogin"] = Url.Action("Index", "Home");
            return Content(resultado.ToString());
        }
        if (!FuncionesGenerales.ValidaPermisos(1))
        {
            resultado["Exito"] = false;
            resultado["Advertencia"] = true;
            resultado["Mensaje"] = Mensajes.MensajePermisoGuardar();
            return Content(resultado.ToString());
        }
        try
        {
            CD_Documentacion cd_d = new CD_Documentacion();

            var User = ((SessionModel)(Session["Usuario" + Session.SessionID])).Usuario;

            var respuesta = cd_d.GuardarDocumento(datosDocumento, User.IdUsuario);
            resultado["Exito"] = true;
            if (respuesta == 1)
                resultado["Mensaje"] = "Documento guardado correctamente.";
            else
                resultado["Mensaje"] = "Documento actualizado correctamente.";
            //resultado["LstMovimientos"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(respuesta);
            return Content(resultado.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            resultado["Exito"] = false;
            resultado["Mensaje"] = ex.Message;
            return Content(resultado.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta configuración va en el archivo web.config. Afecta a toda la aplicación, es decir, creo que no necesitarías cambiarla en cada página.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

"xxx" está en KB. El valor por defecto es 4096 (= 4 MB).